# Conditional loading of templates with Angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, responsive

I want to load different html templates depending on the screen size.

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
    if ($scope.md) {
      return $templateCache.get('library/timelineeditor/slidelibrary/slidelibrary.html')
    } else {
      return $templateCache.get('library/timelineeditor/slidelibrary/slidelibrary-mobile.html')
    }
  }
```

**Directive:**

```
function SlideLibrary() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: true,
    controller: 'SlideLibraryController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>'
  };
}
```

It loads the right template, but something goes wrong along the way as you can see in the pic:

[image]

Are there any best practices around this or do you have any suggestions on how to do it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are passing `template content` to `src` which is trying to make an ajax for fetching that template, that's why you can see 404 error in console. You should just be returning URL form `getTemplateUrl` method. Because `src` of `ng-include` accept `templateUrl` only, it will take care of loading that template into div.

```
$scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
    if ($scope.md) {
      return 'library/timelineeditor/slidelibrary/slidelibrary.html';
    } else {
      return 'library/timelineeditor/slidelibrary/slidelibrary-mobile.html';
    }
}
```